# Why is my bucket name in my R2 object's key?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, cloudflare, cloudflare-r2

I am using Cloudflare R2 with `@aws-sdk/client-s3` inside of a serverless function.

Here I attempt to add an object to my bucket ('my-bucket');

```js
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const s3Client = new S3Client({
 region: "auto",
 endpoint: R2_URL,
 credentials: {
   accessKeyId: R2_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
   secretAccessKey: R2_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
 },
});

const putObject = new PutObjectCommand({
  Bucket: "my-bucket",
  Key: "test.png",
  Body: outputBuffer,
  ContentType: "image/png",
});

s3Client.send(putObjectCommand);
```

In the Cloudflare R2 console I can see that my object was created in the correct bucket but the bucket name is present in the key as `my-bucket/test.png`. I would expect the key to be simply `test.png`.

What can I do to ensure the object is created with only the specified key?

Comment: What is listed if you upload a file to R2 outside of your app?

Comment: @jarmod Do you mean via the R2 console? I can upload an object there and the bucket name is not added to the object's key.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. The code you've shown seems correct. It's maybe worth running it against an actual S3 bucket to verify the correct key is created. If it's correct then I would guess this may be some incompatibility between AWS JavaScript SDK v3 and R2. Worth ensuring that you have the latest AWS SDK v3 and maybe run it with debug logging against R2 to see if the logs suggest anything.

Comment: What is R2_URL? If it includes your bucket name, then you're telling it to upload to `my-bucket/my-bucket/test.png`.

Comment: @Kian You were correct, I had the bucket name in the R2_URL. An oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that the S3 compatible URL in the R2 console includes the bucket name by default when you copy it from the UI.

```
https://<ACCOUNT_ID>.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/<BUCKET_NAME>
```

Removing the `<BUCKET_NAME>` from my `R2_URL` fixed my issue.